# ffmpeg is reducing video duration while compressing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command line to compress my_video.mp4 (duration 5s) and overwrite the initial file.

```
ffmpeg -y -i my_video.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my_video.mp4
```

If I run this command with a video of 5s it is reducing my_video.mp4 to 1s

What is wrong here ? I just want my output file to be the initial file.

If I run

```
ffmpeg -y -i my_video.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my_video2.mp4
```

my_video2.mp4 is compressed and have a duration of 5s and my_video.mp4 have a duration of 1s

I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg does not do in-place editing! Output files have to be different than input files.

Comment: Ok, i use a temporary file and then I copy this file in my inital file, it works thx.